# Grouping Issue in SQL Reporting Services

Tags: sql, reporting-services, grouping

I haven't worked with SQL Reporting much, however I have been trying to get my results to appear in a specific way but I just can't seem to figure out how to format / group my results.

The data that I am receiving from my query resembles the following:

- **ID Number** (This is what the items will be grouped by)
- **Display Name** (Corresponds to ID Number 1:1)
- **Study Date/Time**  (Studies have a many-to-one relationship with ID Numbers)
- **Study Description**

Basically, I am trying to format my results as follows:

```
DISPLAY NAME (NUMBER OF STUDIES)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
STUDY DATE / TIME           |  STUDY DESCRIPTION                                 
----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
01/16/2012 12:34 AM         |  EXAMPLE DESCRIPTION 1
02/22/2012 02:22 PM         |  EXAMPLE DESCRIPTION 2
```

I have tinkered with the grouping several times I am able to have the name appear on the left-hand side and list all of the studies to the right, however I am trying to achieve the appearance listed above but am not having any luck.

Any suggestions would be more than welcome and I will try to provide any additional details if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Group by ID Number.
- Include two group header rows - one for Display Name and count of rows, one for column headings.
- Include a detail row to list study date/time and description.
- You may want to include a group footer with a space in it, to insert a blank line between one group and the next.

Comment: Thanks Mark! - after tinkering with it a bit, it eventually performed as I needed it to.